# Filter on IDs with RediSearch

Tags: filter, redisearch

Is there any way to restrict RediSearch results by a list of document IDs, which would be specified in the request?

e.g. something like `FT.SEARCH cars fast @id:{100,200,300}` would  return only fast cars having ID 100, 200, or 300.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's the INKEYS keyword.

```
> FT.SEARCH cars "fast" INKEYS 3 100 200 300
```

See https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Commands/#ftsearch

Comment: I am not understanding this at all. Could you please explain. This searches for those IDs on what field of the index?

Comment: @ficuscr the primary id of the documents, i.e the actual redis key.

Comment: Ahh. I see. I was looking for a way to filter on documents with a certain category id, not unique. I'll keep searching, or open another question. Thanks.

Comment: @ficuscr that's not a problem. See tag fields. https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Tags/

Comment: This worked. Numeric index. `FT.SEARCH lot_idx "polaris (@category:[1 1] | @category:[33 33] | @category:[70 70])"`

Comment: While that worked, you were right, tags were a much better option and what I ended up using. I was hung up on the value being numeric and not understanding the use cases for tags.